# How to set http.nonProxyHosts in java URL Connection without system property?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I have a system property to exclude hosts to not use proxy. Is it possible to set it without setting the system properties?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you create a [`java.net.Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html), and then use [`URL.openConnection(Proxy)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection-java.net.Proxy-) for the cases when you need one, and `Proxy.NONE` for the cases where you don't.